# How do I know which District Court in my area to go to?

Tags: small-claims-court, court

I see this list of district courts for my county:

http://access.tarrantcounty.com/en/civil-courts/district-courts.html

How do I know which one to go to? Can I just go to the closest one, or do I need
to visit a specific one?

Comment: If anything, all of those courts appear to be at the same address. (Generally, you go to the one closest to you).

Comment: @Zizouz212 whoops, did not see that